# jdk 8 run empty main function , why PSYoungGen already used about 1000k space

Tags: java

when I run an empty main function, and print gc details, but see the PSYoungGen used about 1000k space, I don't allocate any objects, why it already used about 1000k space? The code like followings:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

The GC details as followings(can see used **1374K**):

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 2048K, used 1374K [0x00000007bfd80000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1536K, 89% used [0x00000007bfd80000,0x00000007bfed7ba0,0x00000007bff00000)
  from space 512K, 0% used [0x00000007bff80000,0x00000007bff80000,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x00000007bff00000,0x00000007bff00000,0x00000007bff80000)
 ParOldGen       total 5632K, used 0K [0x00000007bf800000, 0x00000007bfd80000, 0x00000007bfd80000)
  object space 5632K, 0% used [0x00000007bf800000,0x00000007bf800000,0x00000007bfd80000)
 Metaspace       used 2914K, capacity 4496K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 319K, capacity 388K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K
```

The vm options as followings:

```
-Xms8m -Xmx8m -XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory usage you see is used by the JVM itself to maintain its work. If you provide `-verbose` option when running the application, you will see a number of classes being loaded into Metaspace:

(classes loaded on my JVM)

```
[Loaded java.lang.Object from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.Serializable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Comparable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.CharSequence from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.String from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.GenericDeclaration from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.Type from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Class from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Cloneable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.ClassLoader from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.System from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Throwable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]

                                            ...

                                    and many many more
```

They have static fields with objects allocated in the heap which consume memory.

And also do not forget about internal JVM services such as GC, JMX and RMI which can also be instantiated implicitly and consume some memory.

P.S. If you want to get more information on what exactly is being loaded into the heap and how much memory each object consumes, you can inspect your JVM heap dump with any profiling utility, such as [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/).